# unable to re-register cassandra framework on vagrant environment after tearing it down

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I have a vagrant environment setup, with one mesos master and two mesos agents. After, registering the cassandra framework once, if I tear it down and try to re-register it. It is unable to start cassandra tasks on mesos agent.

What is the reason behind it, who is maintaining the state of previous cassandra framework, such as mesos-master, or zookeeper or mesos-agents?

EDIT:
What I discovered is that, mesos-agent is not offering the resources which were used by previous cassandra framework registration. From my understanding, once the framework is teared down, it should free up resources from mesos-agents also.

EDIT:
When I restart the mesos-master process on vagrant environment, I see all the completed frameworks go away from the mesos UI, so I believe it is clearing up its state but mesos agent's even after re-starting still holds the previous completed frameworks list, so where can I clear up mesos-slave state?

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling Cassandra framework/service, if you would like to re-install it fresh you need to cleanup it's Zookeeper state, please refer to this documentation for more details: https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/managing-services/uninstall/

tl;dr

Run this command from any host within the DC/OS cluster to clear up Zookeeper state w.r.t. Cassandra service:

```
docker run mesosphere/janitor /janitor.py -r cassandra-role -p cassandra-principal -z dcos-service-cassandra
```

Installation uses following defaults:

- Role: cassandra-role
- Principal: cassandra-principal
- ZNode: dcos-service-cassandra

If you changed any of above, please update the command accordingly.